# What would be the Joule requirement to a railgun launch a conventional bullet at mach 7?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, projectile, estimation

The railgun project from the US Naval Surface Warfare Center Dahlgren Division shoots a projectile of 3.2kg at a speed of mach 7 with 18.4 megajoules of energy.

How many joules would a railgun need to shoot a rifle-sized bullet of 3 grams at same speed of mach 7?

By the way, I'm asking about muzzle energy, for the little I think I know, railguns have a maximum efficiency of 47% and mostly is lost due to inneficiencies in the system, heat and other physical requirements (like accelerating something from 0 to mach 7 around 0.0004 seconds).

Of course,due to this, the final result is impossible to tell, so you can see the answer as *"at least x joules of energy, not counting all these factors"*.

---

Well, since the Megajoule railgun projectile weights 3 kg, and the rifle projectile weights 3 grams, 1000 times less, then I simply divided 18 megajoules by 1000, resulting in 18 kilojoules. But I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: From the [help]: avoid asking questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers

Comment: @L.Dutch as a moderator I'm sure you must be aware that this question does not at all match the example question of “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”. The fact that this question would remain the same if the OP removed their answer makes it clear that it does not fall under that rule, and adding your own answer but stating you're not sure whether it's correct is, if anything, helpful to answerers as it shows the querent's thought process.

Comment: @L.Dutch I understand this as "I have this math. Is it correct?" instead of "I have this answer, please give me more". It feels like the OP is providing their research (something we want, even if it is quite basic), and as such the question would be on-topic.

Comment: Keep in mind that the muzzle energy of a projectile will always be less than the energy that was used to accelerate it. The energies in your post describe the muzzle energy, yet it seems like you're asking for the energy required per shot. Can you [edit] this post to clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This belongs on Physics.SE. It's not clear that it's speculative at all. It's about real energy math.

Comment: For chat GPT asking to get the relevant formula would be more useful. In this case kinetic energy. Compare the two scenarios and figure out your unknowns. Given prior information ask chatGPT more questions get it to provide an explanation., If you know the formula units and numbers involved you should be able to verify.

Comment: Subsidiary to the answer (kinetic energy is kinetic energy), a 3g rifle bullet is going to experience a lot more resistance per unit mass from air than a 3kg railgun slug.

Comment: I think the tag should be switched from hard-science to science-based. It's going to be hard or impossible to write up an unequivocal answer describing a very fictional weapon.

Comment: Note that 3g is a tiny rifle bullet, you're talking about a .22.  Which means that it is going to slow down horrendously quickly if it's in an atmosphere - unless you're pressing the railgun's muzzle into the target most of the velocity and energy will be dissipated in heating the projectile and the air around it.  Or is this for use in a vacuum, which will make a significant difference to the answer?

Comment: The question got insta closed, so I just forgot about it. Sorry for taking so long to fix the issues.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I searched on google the weight of a  M16A1 carabin used by the US and it weights around 3.6 grams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing all the intricacies of the weapon, the best approximation I can give is by determining the kinetic energy of a 3 gram projectile moving at mach 7, which is roughly 2400 m/s.

KE = 1/2mv^2
KE = 1/2(0.003)*2400^2
KE = 8640 Joules

For future reference, this [kinetic energy calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/physics/kinetic.php) is very useful for doing such calculations.